# Why readdir returns null and I/O error the next call to readdir after first call on a directory

Tags: c, linux, readdir

```
DIR *dir_ptr;
struct dirent *dir_entery;
dir_ptr = opendir("/tmp");

while (dir_ptr&&(dir_entery = readdir(dir_ptr))) {
   printf("%s \n", dir_entery->d_name);
}

printf("%s \n", strerror(errno));
```

gives this output:

```
file_name
dir_name
errno = Remote I/O error
```

in `/tmp` I have one dir and two files when get to readdir after the execution of `opendir(dir)` It exits the while and put this error:

```
errno = Remote I/O error
```

Why it fails to read the file after the dir in the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: Read the manual carefully http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir

Comment: errno 121 is `EREMOTEIO` (Remote I/O error). Perhaps there are permission problems on the target file system. Did you tried your program to run with root (supper user) permission, if you are in Ubuntu try with `sudo`

Comment: I would assume that the 2nd file has unusual attributes, name, access rights, etc.  Try runing in a lower directory.  Maybe its choking on ".."?

Comment: I chmod all the files in `/tmp`: `chmod -R 0777 /tmp`

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la /tmp`? Hide the actual file names if you need to keep them private.

Comment: Regarding `EREMOTEIO` please also see my updated answer below. You seem to be on the wrong trail ...

Comment: Is the code posted the exact code you are using to produce the issues described? Form the output you show I doubt this.

Comment: @user315052 IT CONTAINS 1 DIR AND TWO FILES FOR SURE ALL 0777.

Comment: @akhil WHY DO YOU THINK I DIDN'T READ IT ?

Comment: No need to get so frustrated. I am trying to figure out what `ls` is doing that is different from what your program is doing, and seeing the output is one way to diagnose it. It seems you are unwilling to share the output. Is your program multi-threaded?

Comment: @akhil I wasn't frustrated, sorry if I misunderstood. no multi-threaded the device is not accessible for me now.

Answer (score 1):

`readdir()` is not documented to return `REREMOTEIO`, so most likely `sterror()` gives misleading information.

Set `errno` to `0` **before** entering the `while()` loop, that is **before** calling `readdir()`.

From [`man readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html):

> If the end of the directory stream is reached, NULL is returned and  *errno*  is  not
>   changed.  If an error occurs, NULL is returned and *errno* is set appropriately. To distinguish end of stream and from an
>          error, set *errno* to zero before calling **readdir()** and then check the
>          value of *errno* if NULL is returned.

To test these **two** cases when `readdir()` returns `NULL` you might like to modify your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

  ...

  DIR * dir_ptr = opendir("/tmp");
  if (NULL != dir_ptr)
  {
    perror("opendir() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    struct dirent * dir_entery;

    errno = 0; 
    while ((dir_entery = readdir(dir_ptr))) /* an extra pair of parenthesis here to silence GCC */
    {
      printf("%s\n", dir_entery->d_name);
    }

    if (0 != errno)
    {
      perror("readdir() failed");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("No more entries.\n");
    }
  }

  ...
```